# How to make vstack or vertical paging this view?

Tags: swift, xcode, paging, cardview, vstack

I am developing the app like below screen. I want these two kind of view.

1. one is horizontal range view
2. vertical scroll card view. basically the view should be behind to one other. and it can scroll vertically.

and i need animation to one card view to another card view

[image: image is here]

Please tell me what are all the library for this? and suggest me how to do it without library if  it is not available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this view in top you can use custom Progress bar (if you want a pod for this, [you can see this one](https://github.com/gordoneliel/LinearProgressBar)).
For the cards, there is this pods:

- CardsLayout: https://github.com/filletofish/CardsLayout
- Cardslider: https://github.com/Ramotion/cardslider